# How to enforce the height of inner div to be equal to the height of the parent div, if the parent div has "min-height"?

Tags: html, height, css

Why in the following example the height of the inner `div` is not like wrapper's `div` ?

[Live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dqC8t/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Peace</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #000;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #777;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If I change `min-height: 100px;` to `height: 100px;`, then it looks OK. But, in my case, I need `min-height`.

Comment: If the height of the wrapper isn't dynamic, then why do you need to use % when the inner could just have the same height that you specified for wrapper. Also, if inner was 100% high then how would having two of them within wrapper work..?

Comment: thanks for that site btw Misha, it will be very helpful :)

Comment: @iain: Welcome to the club :)

Comment: @Marty: The height of the wrapper **is** dynamic, it can be 100px or more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is the output you want: http://jsfiddle.net/xhp7x/

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper2 {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row
}
.inner {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #777;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Had to add a second DIV wrapper2.

Tested on chrome and firefox.

Comment: In your example the wrapper does not has `min-height`.

Comment: but it behave like so. the short text keep the wrapper at 100px, and the tall text extend it

Comment: OK... But the height of the inner wrappers is less than the height of the wrapper. I want them to be equal.

Comment: Edited. Sorry, was working on chrome. Now is working on firefox. Cant make it work in IE though... will keep trying

Comment: hi.. it's impossible to work in IE, unless you specify the height of the containing div. sorry.

Answer (score 10):

Some properties in CSS inherit the value of the parent automatically, some don't. Minimum height must be explicitly stated when you want it to inherit the parent's value:

```
min-height: inherit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify both, CSS `height` is not the same as `min-height`. You want to specify both `height` and `min-height`.

- `height`  = When used as a `%`, this is a percent of the window height
- `min-height` = as you drag the window smaller, the DIV with a `%` `height` will continue to reduce until it hits the `min-height`
- `max-height` = as you drag the window larger, the DIV with a `%` `height` will continue to increase until it hits the `max-height`

http://jsfiddle.net/gpeKW/2/ I've added a sample here with borders.

Slight change to the answer from your comment, you are pretty much correct from your original CSS.

The below HTML will have a minimum div height of 100px. As the size of the inner DIV increases, the wrapper will automatically expand. I have demonstrated this by adding a `style` attribute to the first inner `class`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapper
        {
            background-color: #000;
            min-height:100px;
        }
        .inner
        {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #777;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="inner" style="height:200px">test</div>
    <div class="inner">Peace</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried that but if you put height the div dont grow if the content if larger than 100px, i guess that's a prerequisite

Comment: In your example there is no `min-height` on the wrapper div.

Comment: @misha, i updated it, sorry i had trouble with the copy and paste :)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to define wrapper's `height`. I want it to be 100px or more (in case case the inner div is too tall).

Answer (score 0):

I know one way to set the div child height the same as its parent div height is to use relative for the parent and absolute position for the child.

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: #000;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #777;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But this way will cause some problem, you have to adjust the child element so that it will be displayed properly

P/s: Why don't you set it to the same height as its parent height? I mean, 100% is not x%... just thinking..

Anyway, happy coding ;)

Comment: hm.. weird, it didn't expand the height for a high element http://jsfiddle.net/kBRVH/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kBRVH/3/ as you can see, the first one with text in black, if you insert more lines, it will overflow the outside div, because the outside div is 100px high and this height will not increase when its child with absolute position increases height. On the other hand, the second one with white text, insert more lines and you will see ;)

Answer (score 0):

I certainly joined answers and the result using 'min-height' for the -*main HTML tag*- **(class = "main-page-container")**:

HTML:

```
<div id="divMainContent">
    <!-- before or after you can use multiples divs or containers HTML elements-->
    <div>   </div>
    <div>   </div>
    
    <main class="main-page-container">
        <div class="wrapper">
        1
            <div class="wrapper2">
            2
                <div class="child">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <!-- before or after you can use multiples divs or containers HTML elements-->
    <div class="footer-page-container bg-danger" > more relevant info</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*#region ---- app component containers ---- */
#divMainContent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  /*optional: max width for screens with high resolution*/
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.main-page-container {
  display: inline-table;
  height: 70%;
  min-height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-page-container{
  flex:1; /* important in order to cover the rest of height */

  /* this is just  for your internal html tags
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between; */
}

/*#endregion ---- app component containers ---- */


.wrapper {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 1280px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper2 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 90%;
}

.child {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
}
```